# Nested {{each}} loops with Handlebars template

Tags: json, templates, handlebars.js

Im trying to iterate an Array of Objects for putting their values in a Handlebars template using the each loop inside the structure of the array.
Here you can see the array:

```js
var datosSensores = [    
    {
        name:'John Pinard',
        email:'jp@aol.com',
        ph: [
            '7.80',
            '7.90',
            '7.60',
            fecha: [
                '2016-06-20 09:00',
                '2016-06-21 10:00'
            ],
        
        ],
        
    }
];
```

And the each loop if've tried as you can see:

```js
{{#each ph}}
....
.....
    {{#each ph.fechaPH}}
        {{this.fechaPH}} //This would be the value of each DATE in the array
    {{/each}}  

{{/each}}
```

I dont know how to solve it or what I'm doing wrong.
I appreciate any comment about this issue
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You're almost using the correct syntax :

```
{{#each ph}}
....
.....
    {{#each fecha}}
        {{this}} //This would be the value of each DATE in the array
    {{/each}}  

{{/each}}
```

When you're inside a #each loop the this object becomes the "root" node so you don't need to name ph.fecha but just fecha as ph is the root.

[Edit] : I've changed the name fechaPH does not exist in your example it is fecha.

Answer (score 5):

```
{#each main}}  
  {{#each sub}} 
    <p>{{ ../dataOfMain }}</p>
    <p>{{ subData }}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: here please not {{#each }} this is using for forEach and thr "../" is used for parrant loop

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, please [edit] with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and [answer].