# how i can make one each inside a each in handlebars?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

hello everyone i need one each inside a each in handlebars

```
{{#each daychecker}}
 <div>
  {{#each daychecker.image }}
 <h1>{{this.url}}</h1>
 {{/each}}
 </div>
 {{else}}
 <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 24rem; background: #b8974d;box-shadow: 3px 2px 10px 
 1px #0000007a;">
 <div class="card-body">
   <center>
 <h1>Bienvenido {{user.nombre}}</h1>
 <br>
    <p class="lead" style="    margin-bottom: 0px;">No hay platos disponibles aún.</p>
     <p class="lead">Nuestro horario es de lunes a viernes.</p>
 </center>
 </div>
 </div>

 {{/each}}
```

this is my json, it's the mongodb data and I pass it to handlebars so you can read correctly:

```
{
ingredientes: {
proteinas: [ [Object], [Object] ],
granos: [ [Object] ],
otros: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
},
popularidad: 0,
adicional: [
{ nombre: 'doble proteína', precio: '3000' },
{ nombre: 'doble proteína mixta', precio: '3000' }
],
retirar_adicional: [ { nombre: 'sin salsa' }, { nombre: 'sin chips de 
papa criolla' } ],
bebidas_var: [
{ nombre: 'Limonada de coco', precio: '5000' },
{ nombre: 'Limonada de coco sin cubiertos', precio: '4500' },
{ nombre: 'limonada natural sin azúcar', precio: '4000' },
{
  nombre: 'limonada natural sin azúcar sin cubiertos',
  precio: '3500'
 },
{ nombre: 'Sin bebida y sin cubiertos', precio: '0' },
{ nombre: 'Sin bebida y con cubiertos', precio: '0' }
],
image: [
  {
  url: 
  'hola',
  p_id: 'okgkprhgfl6i6sauopr1'
}
],
_id: 5da177dcbfdb2b586a0a3e03,
nombre: 'Hamburguesa de pollo',
descripcion: 'Hamburguesa de pollo crispy con tajada de queso y 
tocineta con salsa a base de queso y chips de papa criolla',
precio: '12800',
diaplato: 'sábado',
createdAt: 2019-10-12T06:51:08.958Z,
updatedAt: 2019-10-12T06:51:08.958Z,
__v: 0
}
```

this is my get in node.js

```
router.get('/resume', isAuthenticated,  async (req, res) => {
// role check menu
data = req.user.role
var role = false;
if(data == "admin"){
    role = true;
}


// day displayer
var day = moment.weekdays(moment().day());
var daychecker = (await Platos.findOne({ diaplato: day })).toJSON();


res.render('resume/resume',{layout: 'index/formatlog.hbs', role, 
daychecker});
});
```

I need them both in this way if I do exactly the same thing, but outside of each parent, any help would work perfectly.

I make one video for more info sorry for my english jeje:
http://sendvid.com/mhxcdiii

**daychecker** is a object

thanks :)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805977/nested-each-loops-with-handlebars-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing

```
{{#each daychecker.image }}
```

With:

```
{{#each image }}
```

Also, try replacing

```
<h1>{{this.url}}</h1>
```

With just:

```
<h1>{{url}}</h1>
```

It [appears](https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) you don't need the dot syntax when accessing properties in a nested each loop.

Comment: Also try replacing `<h1>{{this.url}}</h1>` with just `<h1>{{url}}</h1>`

Comment: See this fiddle as a reference - http://jsfiddle.net/9hw8mxb0/

Comment: Is your API response an array of objects of just a singular object?